# Exporting / Importing React Components Without Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there anyway to export React E6S class Components and then use them in other files without `export default`?

I'm using React outside of the Node framework and so far, have tried all of the obvious methods including jQuery to no avail.

```
$.getScript("components/Component.js", function(){

   alert('it worked');

});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: This is done is by using a module loader like browserify or webpack. You don't need to run a node server, but these are node command line tools that bundle up your files into a single javascript file. It's worth the effort

Comment: @azium I've used them before but only really with Node. Is there anyway to get webpack to auto-build on file saves outside of using a Node Server? That's the only reason I haven't implemented it.

Comment: Why without Node? (again you don't need a Node *server*) Node runs javascript files on your desktop--it runs on windows, linux, mac

Comment: @azium ... well then. I feel ... not too smart. I'll check that out right now!

Comment: install node then follow this: https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack if you get stuck come back to stackover flow with any errors

Comment: @azium Will do, thank you so much for the guidance! If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.